# bash: install_path: No such file or directory

Tags: unity, bashrc

When I open a new terminal I get :
bash: install_path: No such file or directory

My .bashrc file conatins the following code :

```
# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'

# Add an "alert" alias for long running commands.  Use like so:
#   sleep 10; alert
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if [ -f /etc/bash_completion ] && ! shopt -oq posix; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
fi
source /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash
source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=<install_path>/local/lib:/home/enova6/catkin_ws/devel/lib:/opt/ros/hydro/lib
export PATH=<install_path>/local/bin:/home/enova6/catkin_ws/devel/bin:/opt/ros/hydro/bin:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=<install_path>/local/lib/pkgconfig:/home/enova6/catkin_ws/devel/lib/pkgconfig:/opt/ros/hydro/lib/pkgconfig
source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
source /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash
```

Why do i have this problem and how can i fix it ??

Answer (score 1):

The `.bashrc` file is sourced from `.profile` file whenever you open a new Terminal (non-login shell.) 
The problem in your `.bashrc` file is shown as an error on the terminal. There are erraneous lines in your .bashrc. You need to remove `<install_path>` from it. 
What you can do is:

1) Put this line at top:
    `install_path=/opt`

Note: You need to put a path suitable to you. /opt is just for example.

2) Remove any reference to `<install_path>` with `$install_path`, e.g., 
`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$install_path/local/lib:/home/enova6/catkin_ws/devel/lib:/opt/ros/hydro/lib`